# finding the P matrix (diagonalization of a matrix)

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to find the diagonalization of a matrix :

this is my matrix :

$$
        A =\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

for the eigenvalues I found :

$$l_1 = l_2 = 1\quad; \quad  l_3=-1$$

and for the eigenvectors I found :

$$ v_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
        -1\\-1\\1
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
 $$v_2=\begin{pmatrix}
        0\\0\\1
        \end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad v_3 =\begin{pmatrix}
        -1\\1\\0
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

but if I want to find the matrice P will it be :

$$
        A =\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Or:

$$
        A =\begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Or:

$$
        A =\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        -1 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

etc....

I mean there is many ways to write the P matrix, but which one is the correct one ?

Comment: They're all correct. Every $P^{-1}AP$ will be diagonal. But the diagonal elements (= eigenvalues) are shuffled from one to the other.

Comment: @Amzoti That's too kind, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you write the diagonal matrix. Let's assume that $ D=P^-1AP $. Let's assume that we have the following eigenvalues (they are not necessarily different), $ \lambda_1 ,...\lambda_n $, with the following eigenvectors $ \forall i \in [1,n], Av_i=\lambda_i v_i$.

If we write $ D=diag(\lambda_1....\lambda_n)$, then $ P=(v_1....v_n)$, meaning, we put the eigenvector in the column of the fitting eigenvalue in the diagonal matrix.